# How to limit the result in sqllite

Tags: sqlite

I want to apply this query on the database. There is problem in limit function. Please help me to solve this probem.

This is the database. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-mwsQHaJHbVzIDXVsj9jw35ZO8TyV6qM/view?usp=drivesdk

```
    SELECT Track.Track, Artist.Artist, Album.Album, Genre.Genre FROM Track JOIN Genre JOIN Album JOIN Artist ON Track.genre_id = Genre.ID and Track.album_id = Album.id AND Album.artist_id = Artist.id ORDER BY Artist.Artist, Track.Track LIMIT 3
```

**Error**

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "limit": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT Track.Track, Artist.Artist, Album.Album, Genre.Genre FROM Track JOIN Genre JOIN Album JOIN Artist ON Track.genre_id = Genre.ID and Track.album_id = Album.id   AND Album.artist_id = Artist.id ORDER BY Artist.Artist, Track.Track LIMIT 3 limit 20 offset 0
```

Comment: Hi Navneet, share us please what's the problem actually?

Comment: I have shared the error

Comment: That error message is not coming from the sql query in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error carefully: the end of the message says the following

```
... ORDER BY Artist.Artist, Track.Track LIMIT 3 limit 20 offset 0
```

There is a second "limit" clause appended to the query and this is why sqlite can't process it.

I believe your code appends "limit 20 offset 0" to the query automatically. Check the way how you create the query. The error is definitely there.

Comment: I am giving only one limit. Accorsing to you, problem ia in the query but I didn't underatood what'sthe problwm in query. Please check the query. Please help me

Comment: @NavneetKaur, I've updated the answer. Check the end of the error message you've postet

Comment: I have seen the end of the error message. But i didn't wrote that.This is automattically written. What i can do for that ?

Comment: @NavneetKaur you have 2 options: 1. on the android side find the place where this "limit 20 offset 0" clause being appended and fix it. Or you might go option 2 and just remove "limit 3" from the query. It depends on the application logic you're developing.

Comment: I solved this by adding ; in the last of the query. I can't imagine that semi colon can make this big mistake.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @NavneetKaur it just made the query to look like "SELECT ... LIMIT 3; limit 20 offset 0" and the sqlite ignored the rest of line that came after semi-colon. This not a solution, but a good workaround. Well done!